# CRS mismatch - Geopandas.clip

Tags: coordinate-system, clip, geopandas

I am working on a script that will iterate through a grid and clip out polygons that lay within their respective grid cell. I am running into a CRS mismatch error exclaiming that my left and right CRS's do not match. I tired setting them with `to_crs()`, but it changes my `data type` to `None`. My second issue that I run into is a `No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)` Well that should be because I no longer have a dataframe (class Nonetype).

Any advice?

```
import geopandas
import shapefile
import rasterio
import glob
import pandas

save_name = 0

little_polygon_path = 'D:/data/shape_merge/'
little_polygon_extent = geopandas.read_file(little_polygon_path + 'little_polygon_merge.shp')
little_polygon_extent.to_crs(epsg=32610, inplace=True)
little_polygon = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(little_polygon)

big_shape_extent_path = 'D:/data/extents/'
big_shape = geopandas.read_file('D:/data/extents/big_polygon.shp')
big_shape.to_crs(epsg=32610, inplace=True)
big_shape = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(big_shape)

for each_shape in little_polygon_extent.iterrows():
    df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(each_shape[1])

    clip_shape = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape)
    xmin = clip_shape['geometry'].bounds['minx']
    xmax = clip_shape['geometry'].bounds['maxx']
    ymin = clip_shape['geometry'].bounds['miny']
    ymax = clip_shape['geometry'].bounds['maxy']

    p1 = ((xmin.iat[0]), (ymin.iat[0]))
    p2 = ((xmax.iat[0]), (ymin.iat[0]))
    p3 = ((xmax.iat[0]), (ymax.iat[0]))
    p4 = ((xmin.iat[0]), (ymax.iat[0]))

    shp_path = 'D:/data/clipped/'

    w = shapefile.Writer(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.shp')
    w.field("name", "C")  # pyshp needs at least one field
    w.poly([[p4, p3, p2, p1]])  # generate bbox polygon
    w.record('box')
    w.close()

    # generate .PRJ file
    tif_file = 'D:/farmer_32610.tif'
    image = rasterio.open(tif_file)
    crs_wkt = image.crs.to_wkt()
    prj = open(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.prj', "w")
    prj.write(crs_wkt)
    prj.close()

    save_name = save_name + 1



root = 'D:/data/clipped/'
path = 'D:/data/clipped_merge/'
shapefiles = glob.glob(root + '/' + '/*.shp')
gdf = pandas.concat([
geopandas.read_file(shp)
for shp in shapefiles
]).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
# gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:32610'}
gdf.to_file(path + '/' + 'clipped_merge.shp')
```

Error Output before using `to_crs()`. After using `to_crs()` the CRS issue is cleared, but the "geometry" column issue occurs.

```
D:\PycharmProjects\one.py:23: UserWarning: CRS mismatch between the CRS of left geometries and the CRS of right geometries.
Use `to_crs()` to reproject one of the input geometries to match the CRS of the other.

Left CRS: None
Right CRS: EPSG:32610

  clip_shape = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\one.py", line 23, in <module>
    clip_shape = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape)
  File "C:\Users\zlesl\anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\clip.py", line 140, in clip
    box_gdf = gdf.total_bounds
  File "C:\Users\zlesl\anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5462, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\zlesl\anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\base.py", line 2577, in total_bounds
    return GeometryArray(self.geometry.values).total_bounds
  File "C:\Users\zlesl\anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5462, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\zlesl\anaconda3\envs\testing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 186, in _get_geometry
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)
```

**Edits**. Needed to add these two lines because the `to_crs()` changes the data type to `None`. When I print out `little_polygon` and `big_shape`, I get a geopandas data frame that is empty.

```
little_polygon = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(little_polygon)
big_shape = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(big_shape)
```

**Edits 2**. So it seems that the `CRS mismatch` is actually a [bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347732/finding-distance-of-consecutive-points-in-a-geopandas-data-frame) and can just be ignored. So I don't need to include the `to_crs()` anymore. With the updated code below I still however get the `geometries` error. `little_polygon` and `big_shape` are GeoDataFrames and calling `head()` to them outputs a column containing the geometry. I'll keep trouble shooting. I also changed `iterrows` to `itertuples` because there are some problems with the geometry data being currupted.

```
little_polygon_path = 'D:/data/shape_merge/'
little_polygon_extent = geopandas.read_file(little_polygon_path + 'little_polygon_merge.shp')


big_shape_extent_path = 'D:/data/extents/'
big_shape = geopandas.read_file('D:/data/extents/big_polygon.shp')


for each_shape in little_polygon_extent.itertuples():
    df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(each_shape)
```

**Edits 3**. Using `itertuples()` changes the data type to a pandas data frame. I was able to index out the geometry and tried creating my own GeoDataFrame though am running into a different error: `tuple object has no attribute 'is_empty'`.

```
for each_shape in little_polygon_extent.itertuples():
    new = Polygon(each_shape[2])
    df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [new.bounds]})

    shape_clip = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape, keep_geom_type=True)
```

Comment: Inspect the all your GeoDataFrames (e.g. clip_shape.head()) and what do you see?

Comment: line 23 is where the error is being called, line 23 is the `clip_shape = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape)`. So I am not even getting to those GeoDataFrames.

Comment: Right - but clipping GeoDataFrame returns a GeoDataFrame: https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.clip.html?highlight=clip#geopandas.clip

Comment: Correct - I added a couple of lines after my two `to_crs()` lines. When I call `to_crs()`. It changes my data type to `None type`. So I needed to turn it back into a GeoDataFrame. When I run the code now, my GeoDataFrames are empty.

Comment: What channel did you install geopandas from? Did you explicitly state a channel for you anaconda environment like it says here https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

Comment: Yeah I used `conda install geopandas`. I did not create a new environment.

Comment: can you confirm you do not have are calling .clip() correctly? maybe you want keep_geom=True? look at the documentation i linked earlier

Comment: I included the `keep_geom=True`, but still get the error. `itertuple` chanses the data type to a Pandas data frame, which cannot be clipped with `big_shape`. If I try `df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(each_shape)` I get the "geometry" error. With and without `keep_geom_type`.

Comment: can you print out an example `each_shape[1]` ?

Comment: Just solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have finally figured it out. Along with my **edits**, I needed to pass a `try` block becuase some `little_polygon` were completely outside of my `big_shape` polygon. This will throw and error due to the `each_shape` variable will contain no data. So when `p1` trys to grab xmin and ymin, there is no data to grab. The `try` block allows me to see if there is any data there. If there isn't go to the next polygon. If there is, complete the rest of the code.

```
import geopandas
import shapefile
import rasterio
import glob
import pandas
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

save_name = 0

little_polygon_path = 'D:/data/shape_merge/'
little_polygon_extent = geopandas.read_file(little_polygon_path + 'little_polygon_merge.shp')


big_shape_extent_path = 'D:/data/extents/'
big_shape = geopandas.read_file('D:/data/extents/big_polygon.shp')

for each_shape in little_polygon_extent.itertuples():
    new = Polygon(each_shape[2])
    df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [new.bounds]})

    shape_clip = geopandas.clip(df, big_shape, keep_geom_type=True))

    xmin = bbox_clip['geometry'].bounds['minx']
    xmax = bbox_clip['geometry'].bounds['maxx']
    ymin = bbox_clip['geometry'].bounds['miny']
    ymax = bbox_clip['geometry'].bounds['maxy']

    try:
        p1 = ((xmin.iat[0]), (ymin.iat[0]))
    except:
        pass
    else:
        p1 = ((xmin.iat[0]), (ymin.iat[0]))
        p2 = ((xmax.iat[0]), (ymin.iat[0]))
        p3 = ((xmax.iat[0]), (ymax.iat[0]))
        p4 = ((xmin.iat[0]), (ymax.iat[0]))

        shp_path = 'D:/data/clipped/'

        w = shapefile.Writer(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.shp')
        w.field("name", "C")  # pyshp needs at least one field
        w.poly([[p4, p3, p2, p1]])  # generate bbox polygon
        w.record('box')
        w.close()

        # generate .PRJ file
        tif_file = 'D:/farmer_32610.tif'
        image = rasterio.open(tif_file)
        crs_wkt = image.crs.to_wkt()
        prj = open(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.prj', "w")
        prj.write(crs_wkt)
        prj.close()

        save_name = save_name + 1



root = 'D:/data/clipped/'
path = 'D:/data/clipped_merge/'
shapefiles = glob.glob(root + '/' + '/*.shp')
gdf = pandas.concat([
geopandas.read_file(shp)
for shp in shapefiles
]).pipe(geopandas.GeoDataFrame)
# gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:32610'}
gdf.to_file(path + '/' + 'clipped_merge.shp')
```